# Touch handler called in a destroyed object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I find myself confused as to why I cant stop my touch handler from being called:

In DungeonDisplay.m:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (processing || animating) 
        return false;
    processing =  true;
    touchPoint = [self locationFromTouch:touch];
    [self schedule:@selector(keepMoving) interval:0.01];
    [self processTouchAtX:(touchPoint.x/32) AndY:(touchPoint.y/32)];
    return false;
}

-(void) processTouchAtX: (int)x AndY: (int)y
{
//    if (theDungeon.currentDungeonLevel)
         [theDungeon processTouchAtX:x AndY:y];
}
```

Now, in [theDungeon processTouchAtX:x AndY:y] the DungeonDisplay instance gets released and DungeonDisplay:Dealloc is called correctly, but as I step through the function ccTouchBegan, right after the last "return false;" the next "step" returns to the top of the function "if (processing || animating)" and the next step crashes the program.

I am unclear as to what the problem might be.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough code included here. But it is likely due to the fact that you did not NIL out the pointer to the delegate that receives touch events. If your done with something that was a delegate to something else, you MUST make sure that you tell that thing your NO LONGER a delegate. Sending messages in iOS to nil is ok. Sending messages to pointers to released objects is not.

Comment: NULL and nil are different things in iOS. sending a message to nil will do nothing, sending message to NULL will crash the program as in c++, when you try to call method from object that is already NULL

Comment: Actually NULL and nil are different names for the same thing. In MacTypes.h nil is defined as: #define nil NULL

Answer (score 0):

If DungeonDisplay is not derived from CCLayer and you registered touches with the CCTouchDispatcher, then make sure to call removeDelegate on CCTouchDispatcher in the cleanup or dealloc methods. Otherwise CCTouchDispatcher will continue to send ccTouch* messages to the object, even if it has been deallocated.